# Collect newman cli reporter logs into a string in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, newman, postman-newman

I have a case wherein I need to capture the logs generated by Newman CLI reporter under newman.run() function inside the Nodejs code and use it for later. There is no such option under reporter to capture the logs inside a file or a stream. Any suggestions for the same?

```
newman.run({ 
                collection: file.json, 
                reporters : ['cli'], 
                },function (err, summary) { 
                        if (err) { 
                        console.log(err); 
                });
```

I need access to the logs inside the callback function.

Update:
Attaching required logs for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [`console`](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/wiki/Newman-Run-Events) event can capture the logs

```
newman.run({
        collection: file.json, 
        reporters : ['cli'], 
    }).on('console', (error, args) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        console.log(args.messages);
    })
```

Demo

REST API to get `category` with console.log() in `Tests` tab.

```
https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=17
```

In `Tests` Tab

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var category = jsonData["results"][0]["category"]
var question = jsonData["results"][0]["question"]

console.log("category: " + category);
console.log("question: " + question);
```

[image]

##### Full collection for two APIs.

Export as `1-log-demo.postman_collection.json`

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "eaeb4ffe-24aa-4a90-a04a-dd2beaac99e1",
        "name": "1-log-demo",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "_exporter_id": "1826150"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "get Nature",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "\r",
                            "var category = jsonData[\"results\"][0][\"category\"]\r",
                            "var question = jsonData[\"results\"][0][\"question\"]\r",
                            "\r",
                            "console.log(\"category: \" + category);\r",
                            "console.log(\"question: \" + question);"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=17",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "opentdb",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api.php"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "amount",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "category",
                            "value": "17"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "get Computers",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "\r",
                            "var category = jsonData[\"results\"][0][\"category\"]\r",
                            "var question = jsonData[\"results\"][0][\"question\"]\r",
                            "\r",
                            "console.log(\"category: \" + category);\r",
                            "console.log(\"question: \" + question);"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=18",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "opentdb",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api.php"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "amount",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "category",
                            "value": "18"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ]
}
```

##### demo code

`get-console.js`

```
const newman = require('newman'); // require newman in your project

// call newman.run to pass `options` object and wait for callback
newman.run({
    collection: require('./1-log-demo.postman_collection.json'),
    reporters: 'cli'
}).on('console', (error, args) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(args.messages);
})
```

##### Install Dependency

```
npm install newman
```

##### Run it

```
node get-console.js
```

Result

[image]

##### Compare Between `newman` vs `get-console.js`

`newman` (left) vs `get-console.js` (right)

[image]

Comment: Console event will hit only when console is called from script but what I want is to just capture logs which are going to stdout when we use newman cli reporter and use it as a execution logs of the postman collection. Can you please suggest an alternative to achieve this? @bench-vue

Comment: Can you provide ` I want is to just capture logs which are going to stdout` case example with screen image at postman? I don't understand your want item.

Comment: I have updated the question with the screenshot. @bench-vue

Comment: @HrishikeshBawane, I updated my answer with compare `newman run` vs `node get-console.js`.
You are looking for this or something else?